# shall I add a new In-App-Purchase product with every localization language of my App?

Tags: ios, localization, product, in-app-purchase

I selected English as my default language for my IAP App and added some In-App-Purchase products for it.

Then I add a new localization ( Chinese ) for my this IAP app.

Shall I add a new In-App-Purchase product with Chinese localization language of my App for every of my English IAP product seperately?
i.e. Need I add Chinese version of my already existing English In-App-Purchase products again?

Or may I just use the existing English In-App-Purchase products ( for my chinese version IAP products)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS apps, you should just use enter different Localizations for the one in app purchase(easy to enter on iTunes), not create different in-app-purchases.

I have apps using in-app-purchases, available in more than 5 languages.